# Write Serilog logs directly to ElasticSearch

Tags: kibana, serilog

I want to setup a log aggregator. So far I'm leaning towards ElasticSearch/Kibana. In my apps I'm using Serilog, that currently writes to the Windows Event Log. How do I configure Serilog to send the logs to ElasticSearch instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

G'day! There are some details on the [Serilog wiki](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks#elasticsearch) with the following:

```
Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch
```

then:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.ElasticSearch()
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas! Do you work on Octopus Deploy also? I believe we have met IRL :)

Comment: Hey John, just noticed your comment a couple of years late, sorry :-) ... Yes, that was me; I'm no longer at Octopus, but still working in the "DevOps" space. Thanks for saying g'day!

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt, your comment made me feel warm inside (I'm not the person you replied to)